# Trying to convert uppercase char to lowercase in C without using a function

Tags: c, arrays, uppercase, lowercase

I am trying to convert a char element from an char *argv[] array to lowercase from uppercase without using a function. I want to add 32 to the ascii integer.

When I try to pass the variable as an argument, it will show  the integer sum, but not the new lowercase character. Instead it shows the following output:

```
letter h, 104
tolower: 136, �
```

Code:

```
int i = 0;
for(i = 0; argv[1][i] != '\0'; i++) {
    char letter = argv[1][i];

    printf("letter %c, %i\n", letter, letter);
    char tolower = argv[1][i];
    int lowercase = tolower + 32;

    printf("tolower: %i, %c\n", lowercase, lowercase);
}
```

Why is it printing a "?" char?

Comment: Do not call a variable `tolower` it's the name of a standard function.

Comment: `h` is already lowercase.

Comment: You have to check that  `letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'Z'`

Answer (score 3):

First, don't assume you are using an ascii character set (ie, 32 is the wrong additive value in some character sets).  The problem you are having is that 'h' + 32 is not a lower case "h".  'h' is already lowercase, so you want to be adding 0.  Check it; something like:

```
if( tolower >= 'A' && tolower <= 'Z' )
  tolower += 'a' - 'A';
```

Comment: Oops.  `&&` was intended.

Comment: @MattMcNabb if `&` was "correct" but `&&` "idiomatic" why does MSCV issue the warning *C4554: '&' : check operator precedence for possible error; use parentheses to clarify precedence*?It wasn't correct, it was wrong.

Comment: @WeatherVane don't ask me to explain why MSVC does anything

Comment: @MattMcNabb I am asking you to explain your comment. Why is it right to mix bitwise with boolean?

Comment: @WeatherVane The code with `&` complied with the C standard and correctly implemented the programmer's intent.  However it is more common practice and better style to use `&&` instead.

Comment: @MattMcNabb this is not C++ it is C.

Comment: @MattMcNabb oh you edited it. Thank you for your reluctant approval.

Answer (score 2):

I will not point the problems that other answerers did, I will show a neat trick  to perform the swap upper-lower. For the letters, the difference between the lower case and the upper case letters is the bit 5 in the ascii code. So to set the letter lowercase you need to set this bit:

```
lower = 0x20 | letter;
```

For uppercase reset the bit:

```
upper = (~0x20) & letter;
```

And to swap the case you can use XOR:

```
swapped = 0x20 ^ letter;
```

The good thing here that you don't have to worry and check whether or not the letter is already the case you need.

Of course the assumption here is that your system is using ASCII encoding.

Answer (score 1):

This is from my own C++ library, but it works for C too as well.

**Self-Optimized (Library Function)**

```
// return the specified letter in lowercase
char tolower(int c)
{
    // (int)a = 97, (int)A = 65
    // (a)97 - (A)65 = 32
    // therefore 32 + 65 = a
    return c > 64 && c < 91 ? c + 32 : c;
}
// return the specfied letter in uppercase
char toupper(int c)
{
    // (int)a = 97, (int)A = 65
    // (a)97 - (A)65 = 32
    // therefore 97 - 32 = A
    return c > 96 && c < 123 ? c - 32 : c;
}
```

> The return value is a **printable char**. However, some **modern** compilers
>   may have optimized the code as this already if you're going to do the way below.

**Readable**

```
char tolower(int c)
{
    return c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' ? c + ('a' - 'A') : c;
}
char toupper(int c)
{
    return c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' ? c - ('a' - 'A') : c;
}
```

> Note that the difference between `a` and `A` is a **32** constant.

Comment: Do not hard code ASCII values: if you are going to use this method, at least make it more readable as `return (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') ? c + 'a' - 'A' : c;` etc.

Comment: @chqrlie Alright, you've got a point there since this should be a readable answer

Comment: Why do you insist on `32` instead of `'a'` - `'A'` ?

Comment: It's not required, It just slows the code for no reason; more CPU instructions. despite that, the answer is already a known **constant**. and It's the difference between a and A; **32**, *difference* stands for minus in maths. I think it'd be better to create a single-line comment on this rather than consuming more CPU cycles computing in your App/Software or OS. I never compute constants, but I #define them

Comment: I'm afraid your reasoning is incorrect. Unless you are compiling with optimisations disabled, `'a' - 'A'` will not generate an actual subtraction, it is a constant expression that will be evaluated at compile time, so no performance penalty at all. The reason it is advisable to use `'a' - 'A'` instead of harcoding `32` is both portability and readability. `32` is a constant that works for ASCII, but not some other encodings and is magical in the sense that the reader must know this detail about ASCII that is not required for this algorithm.

Comment: The code `return (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') ? c + 'a' - 'A' : c;` does make an some assumptions about the encoding of characters: they are encoded in alphabetical order, form a continuous sequence and therefore the offset between an upper case letter and its lowercase equivalent is constant. The first 2 assumptions imply the third and are correct for ASCII, but the second is false for EBCDIC although the third still holds. Using this function for EBCDIC will lower case all uppercase letters correctly and leave lowercase letter unchanged but will change some other characters values too.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I don't know whether the compiler that I may use is optimizing the code or not, so I always preferred to calculate it all myself (for the Library only) as I said on my 2nd Edit of this post; bad compilers. by the way, I missed that 'a' && 'A' are actually constants themselves by some integer values; not variables. while answering. so they're being calculated at compile time. helpful :)

Comment: it is high time you stop distrusting compilers. Writing code that is readable for humans is way more important than whether the compiler will optimize it or not. Choosing a better algorithm has a larger impact on performance then your micro-optimisations, which cause portability and maintainability nightmares. For a final point, constant folding must performed by the compiler for correct compilation of declarations, you have to explicitly disable it to get an actual calculation and I would not be surprised if your compiler would still perform it in this specific case.

Comment: lol. I can't agree anymore. I think I took too much caution while building this lib which seems to be reflected on my answers on SO too.

Answer (score 0):

Ascii 136 is not a printable character. You should do something like `lowercase = tolower - 'A' + 'a';`, but only if `tolower` is uppercase for sure (it's not in your example).

Comment: ASCII 136 isn't a character at all. ASCII has 128 codepoints, numbered 0-127, encoded in one byte, 0x00 to 0x7F. But, @JAS is probably not using ASCII, anyway.