# C program to capitalize string not working

Tags: c, string

So, for an assignment, I had to finish a code meant to capitalize a string.

What I tried was this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void capitalize(char *str)
{
    int i = 0;
    if (str[i] >= 97 && str[i] <= 122)
    {
        str[i] = str[i] - 32;
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
    }
}

void strCopy(char *str2, char *str1)
{
    while (*str2)
    {
      *str1 = *str2;
      str2++;
      str1++;
    }
    *str1 = '\0';
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char string1[100] = "This is a really long string!";
    char string2[100];
    strCopy(string1,string2);
    capitalize(string2);
    printf("The original string is \"%s\"\n", string1);
    printf("The capitalized string is \"%s\"\n", string2);
}
```

However, when I tried running the code it returned:

> The original string is "This is a really long string!"
>   The capitalized string is "This is a really long string!"

`strcopy` does not seem to be the issue, as it copies the `string1` correctly to `string2`.

I don't understand why `capitalize` is not working, as it seems like it should be going through letter by letter and changing it to **uppercase**, if the letter falls within the **ascii** code for a **lowercase** letter.

I would greatly appreciate someone helping to point out where the error is.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at the `ctype` header. There are some functions which might help you a lot. I guess you need a loop within `capitalize`.

Comment: See my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28908748/trying-to-convert-uppercase-char-to-lowercase-in-c-without-using-a-function/28908892#28908892) about how to change the case of characters the easy way..

Comment: Thank to everyone for helping so quickly! It's relieving to know that my biggest error was not putting in a loop rather than something more severe. All of your suggestions were very helpful, thanks again!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that your `capitilize` function doesn't have a loop. You only ever capitalize the first letter of your string.

You are on the right track but what you are looking for is this:

```
for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i) { // Here we check for the end condition of a string.
                                       // ie. Has the Null termination been reached?
   if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') {
      str[i] = str[i] - ('a' - 'A');
   }
}
```

[Here is a live demo for you to play with!](http://ideone.com/zWFf4T)

Comment: Thank you for the help, this worked as I originally wanted and now I understand what I did wrong!

Answer (score 3):

Your `capitalize()` function only runs for one character. Try like this

```
for (int i = 0 ; str[i] != '\0' ; ++i) {
    if (str[i] >= 97 && str[i] <= 122)
        str[i] = str[i] - 32;
}
```

perform the operation on *every character* until the `'\0'` is found.

Comment: A nice readability improvement would be using `'a'` instead of `97`, `'z'` instead of `122` and `'A' - 'a'` for the difference

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
void capitalize(char *str)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
      if (str[i] >= 97 && str[i] <= 122) {
          str[i] = str[i] - 32;
      }
      i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to fix `capitalize(char *str)` to check all characters of the string,not just single character.A use of pointer can save you from including `<string.h>` to use `strlen()` function,like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void capitalize(char *str)
{
    char *p = str;
    while(*p++) {
        if (*p >= 97 && *p <= 122) {
            *p -= 32;
        }
    }
}

void strCopy(char *str2, char *str1)
{
    while (*str2) {
        *str1 = *str2;
        str2++;
        str1++;
    }
    *str1 = '\0';
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char string1[100] = "This is a really long string!";
    char string2[100];
    strCopy(string1, string2);
    capitalize(string2);
    printf("The original string is \"%s\"\n", string1);
    printf("The capitalized string is \"%s\"\n", string2);
}
```

Comment: Why not use `toupper`?